# mysql unknown column in where clause. a bug?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

what can be the cause?
on the same DB the select statement works as expected:

```sql
select id from line where line.id = 298;
```

but the following  delete statement fails:

```sql
delete from line where line.id = 298;
```

with an error:

```bsh
Unknown column 'line_id' in 'where clause'
```

output of queries:

```bsh
mysql> delete from line where line.id = 298;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'line_id' in 'where clause'

mysql> select id from line where line.id = 298;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 298 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```bsh
mysql> describe line;
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| service_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| src_site_id  | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| dest_site_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Check your query again and note the difference: line_id AND line.id

Comment: I'm inclined to doubt your claim.  In any event, why be so wordy?  `delete from line where id = 298` means the same thing as your `delete` statement.

Comment: ```delete from `line` where `line`.`id` = 298;``` is the recommended MySQL syntax

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis, not a typo. will edit with proof

Comment: No problem, I believe you. This is strange though..

Comment: @Blag, tried that ... no luck

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f3f2/1).

Comment: This could be a trigger build without check, but it that really strange...

Comment: can you send a describe statement for getting more information about the table columns

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis, agree ... poking at it for a while already. recreated the table already, the problem persists. I'm inclined to think that some sort of query caching is in place. Will try to flush

Comment: ```delete from `line` WHERE `id`=298;``` this fail to ?

Comment: @Blag yes, his is something more than just a syntax error.

Comment: you can try `SHOW TRIGGERS;`  for the trigger, but I don't think it's that (BTW, do you have the same error if you change the name of your table ?)

Comment: @Blag, you win !!! Trigger failure. I did not put them there though ... one of my colleagues did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SHOW TRIGGERS;`

If someone put a trigger without checking it on build (**shame on him, that's a really bad thing to do**), then it'll fail your query without telling you anything.

It's really tricky, because you can't see directly the error is trigger related, and if you don't use trigger /don't know they are some, the only way is to rebuild the table by yourself after a drop.

Comment: Thanks, i spent 2 hours on this :S ... shame on me

Comment: You're welcome, glad to be helpful ; And it's not your shame, the one who put the trigger should bring croissants tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

try creating an alias of the table you are deleting from:

```
DELETE FROM line l WHERE l.id = 298
```

this should work fine

Comment: `mysql> DELETE FROM line l WHERE l.id = 298;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
 for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE l.id = 298' at line 1`

Comment: You can use aliases in multiple-table DELETE. See [13.2.2 DELETE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html).